# Advice on Zend or CI for project

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, openid

I have a new site that I am currently in the process of mapping out. The best way to put it would be that it will be A LOT like youtube.

I need openid support, and video upload support. There is no official openid library for CI and the only one it has seems outdated / could become outdated.

However Codeigniter is fast <- pretty much the only thing keeping me from switching over to Zend.

I guess my real question is: is Zend's performance REALLY bad enough to keep me using CI. I know that one can use Zend libraries with CI, but if you are going to use parts of Zend, why not just use the whole thing?

Or would it be beneficial for me to "figure it out" with Codeigniter?

Comment: Or you could go with yiiframework.com which is even faster. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/copenid/#doc Oh, and you can also integrate it with Zend.

Comment: Have you benchmarked a ZF-app with APC and decent cache turned on? There's also some tweaking to try out, typically found in blog posts like this: http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/421-PHP-Framework-Benchmarks-Entertaining-But-Ultimately-Useless.html

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I decided to take your advice and stick with CI and incorporate Zend libraries into it. <- which has turned out to be much easier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well a couple things:

1. Performance of either framework out of the box shouldn't be a key concern. With this type of site (as you've described) you're going to have to optimize DB read/writes as well as cache like a mofo.
2. Given #1, i would use whatever you feel most comfortable with... there's no reason to make the project more difficult than it needs to be.
3. There is absolutely no reason to use Zend Framework in its entirety if you only need one component. Thats the reason its built like it is... so you can pick and choose. I routinely use components from Zend in my preferred framework, Symfony. Don't be afraid to mix and match.
4. Using ZF as full stack is going to be incredibly more time consuming that using CI because a.) you're more familiar with CI and b.) even ZF's full stack leaves A LOT to be desired - there still a ton of glue you're going to have to write, plus if you want an ActiveRecord like db interface with code generation you're going to have to hook in Doctrine, Propel, or whatever you like (I assume CI has an active record implementation out of the box?).

Comment: CI's active record is ~reasonable~ but its fairly easy to implement Doctrine - see http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup for a fairly indepth how-to

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford the time to implement the OpenID library for CI, do so. 
Or, like prodigitalson said, you can use this single component from ZF [CI supports it, probably you'll need to do some modifications].

From my experience, developing with ZF isn't that easy, it takes time to learn and produce a well implemented web app.